# How to create an array of android.util.Pair objects?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an simple array of pairs. The error i'm getting is the following.

```
Error:(66, 101) error: generic array creation
```

Here's my code:

```
Pair<Integer,String>[] testArray = {
             new Pair<>(0, "firstLine"),
             new Pair<>(1, "secondLine")
        };
```

Comment: Generics and arrays don't play nicely together. Make a `List<Pair<Integer,String>>` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't it be new Pair<Integer,String>(0, "firstLine")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Pair<Integer, String>[] test = new Pair[] {
        new Pair(1, "firstLine"),
        new Pair(2, "secondLine")
};
```

Comment: I am using like this...  `Pair<EditText, String> editTextPairs[] = new Pair[]{new Pair<>(editTextUsername, "Please Enter Username..."), new Pair<>(editTextPassword, "Please Enter Passcode...")};`  But, it shows a warning in Android Studio.